# Android Demo App not opening google pay application after I updated my google pay app

Tags: android

Getting an exception :

No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=xyx@idfcbank&pn=xyz&mc=5311&tr=txRefId&tn=txDesc&am=12.0&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }

Followed these steps for Gpay integration.
https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments

fun gpay() {
val GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"

```
    try {

        val uri = Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(GooglePayMaker.SCHEME_UPI)
            .authority(GooglePayMaker.AUTHORITY_PAY)
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_VPA_KEY, JSONConstants.PAYEE_VPA_VALUE)
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_NAME_KEY, JSONConstants.PAYEE_NAME_VALUE)
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_MERCHANT_CODE_KEY, JSONConstants.PAYEE_MERCHANT_CODE_VALUE)
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_TX_REF_ID_KEY, "xyx")
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_TX_DESC_KEY, "xyx")
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_TX_AMT_KEY, "12.0")
            .appendQueryParameter(JSONConstants.PAYEE_CURR_KEY, JSONConstants.PAYEE_CURR_VALUE)
            .build()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = uri
        intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME)
        startForResult.launch(intent)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.d("TAG", "" + exception.message)
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }
}

val startForResult =
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val intent = result.data
        }
    }
```

FYI : using valid credentials.

Comment: Please share your code. So that we can have a look.

Comment: @Rahul added please check

Comment: the code snippet you posted is correct. I guess the documentation in not proper. Is Google Pay UPI is registered on the test device. Just tested on a device with Google Pay installed but UPI not registered and got the same error.